# Let $H=\{\alpha \in S_n:\alpha (1)=1\} (n\gt 1)$ .Prove that $H$ is a subgroup of $S_n$

Tags: group-theory, permutations

> Let $H=\{\alpha \in S_n:\alpha (1)=1\} (n\gt 1) $
>
> Prove that $H$ is a subgroup of $S_n$

There is already a solution to this problem. It is solved via this theorem:
Let H be a finite set of a group G. Then H is a subgroup of G iff H is closed.

However I want to prove it by showing that it has the identity element and for all $\alpha , \beta \in H, \alpha ^{-1} \beta \in H $

First of all I don't know what is identity element here and second what is an inverse of an element here. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identity of the subgroup must always be the identity of the group. We know that the identity permutation is the identity in $S_n$ and indeed $e \in H$, as $e(1) = 1$.

Now let $\sigma \in H$. Then $\sigma$ has inverse $\sigma^{-1}$ in $S_n$. Then we have

$$\sigma(1) = 1 \implies \sigma^{-1}\sigma(1) = \sigma^{-1}(1) \implies \sigma^{-1}(1) = 1 \implies \sigma^{-1} \in H$$

Now finally $H$ is closed under composition, as if $\sigma, \tau \in H$ we have:

$$\sigma\tau(1) = \sigma(1) = 1 \implies \sigma\tau \in H$$

Therefore $H$ is a subgroup of $S_n$.

Answer (score 1):

Identity element (I) will fix every element i.e. I(r) = r for all r from 1 to n. If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ both fix 1, then their inverse and $\alpha \beta$ fix 1 so all of their combinations fall in H.